# Windows Phone 8 Emulator not launching. Error code 0x80131500

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I have problem with Visual Studio 2012 (OS: Windows 8.1 Preview)

1. Create empty project (Windows Phone App)
2. Press F5 to start debugging.

And I get 0x80131500 error code, with no detailed description. Only this: Deployment of application to device failed.

Output:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: PhoneApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Deploying C:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\Bin\Debu\PhoneApp2.xap...
1>Connecting to Emulator WVGA 512MB...
1>Deployment of application to device failed.
1>0x80131500
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem. How it can be solved?

Comment: Have you tried running the emulator separately ?

Comment: @JibranKhan, actually - No. I can't find it in application list. Where it should be?

Comment: same problem i am facing, i have tried run emulator from Hyper-V manager saparately, it was running successfully. and it is happend after installation of this Windows8.1-KB2917929-x64.msu file installation, i didn't know how to uninstall, i tried to restore, but did not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Windows 8.1 Preview` does not support the `Windows Phone 8 sdk` to run on the `Visual Studio 2012`. You cannot run Emulator as well so better you should use a stable `Windows 8 version` for `WP8` development. This is the statement right from `Microsoft Support`

**After you upgrade your OS to Windows 8.1 Preview, you cannot run Windows Phone 8 Software Development Kit (SDK) emulator (XDE.exe) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012**

Reference [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2864215)

Comment: I'm seeing this same error on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but this is also allegedly fixed with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3  http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/07/02/running-the-windows-phone-emulator-on-windows-8-1-preview.aspx

Comment: What is the resolution of this issue. Right now i have installed VS2012 with Update 4 but emulator is not running.

Comment: That's why I hate Microsoft

Comment: @AshishJain, the solution is to install the stable version of Windows to have all features working.

Answer (score 8):

Installing Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 should fix the issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2864215

Comment: Thanks! Installing Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 fixed issue.

Answer (score 3):

For some one who is looking for an answer who has the same issue while working on a virtual environment, [here](http://besmartdev.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/0x80131500-deployment-to-the-device-failed-windows-phone-8/) is a nice article on it

Comment: Glad that I was of some help.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, updating Windows Phone SDK and VS Express 2012 helped on Windows 8.1, but performance is poor.
If it's helpful try installing update to VS:

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/07/02/running-the-windows-phone-emulator-on-windows-8-1-preview.aspx

And updating SDK:

http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Answer (score 2):

**Setup:** Visual Studio 2013 + Windows 8.1 (no betas) + this did work
**Resolution:** Restart the Hyper-V service

Answer (score 1):

I'm also receving this error while simulating the program. i hav win 8 only and vs12 windows phone...

but when i serach info. regarding this error i get i have not hyper-v windows feature. try this feature you have or not and enable it..

Hyper-v Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found this is the key thing to check, as per (WP8) Emulator (XDE) Troubleshooting Tips on msdn:

1. Launch the “Network Connections” manager (from the home screen, type in “View Network Connections”, It will be listed under Settings)
2. Right click on the adapter named: “vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)”
3. For that adapter, the only items that should be checked under “This connection uses the following items:” should be:

   - Client for Microsoft Networks
   - QoS Packet Scheduler
   - File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks
   - Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver
   - Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver
   - Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder
   - Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
   - Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
4. All other items should be unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Windows Phone 8 SDK. Emulator didn't work because Hyper-V was not turned on. I installed Hyper-V from Programs & Features and got the 0x80131500 error.

Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Later i was able to fix the issue by downloading and installing 
Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 from microsoft website.

Comment: I think there is already an answer like that - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20719422/2759848

Answer (score 0):

Try out these steps if using VS 2012 with Windows 8.1 Pro:

1. Uninstall Hyper-V
2. Reboot
3. Install Hyper-V
4. Reboot

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

service Remote server  of you is disable. You could enable remote server! And don't can reinstall Hyper-V. it's working for me!

Answer (score 0):

**I solved with following repair sequence :**

Uninstall Hyper-V
 Reboot

dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
 dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Reboot
 Install Hyper-V

RG