# Can Windows 8 Mobile App development done on a Windows 8.1 Machine

Tags: window, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have VS2012 and Windows Phone VS Express installed on a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine, but I cannot launch the Emulator.

Is there a way to overcome this? Or is there no way to develop windows 8 app using an emulator on a win 8.1 PC?

I have Hyper V enabled. But I still get an compatibility error. Error Code - 0x80131500

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 Emulator not launching. Error code 0x80131500](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17488017/50447)

Answer (score 2):

The linked question seems to suggest that it is not possible to run WP emulator on Windows 8.1, which is not True (any more). Installing [VS 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) should fix the problem.